# telprompt without alert

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My app need to dial a number and I know that `telprompt` return back to app after dial. But it will alert user every time want to call a number, is there any way to direct call number without show a alert view?

Comment: No. Apple wont allow that. If that is allowed, someone can make an app which dials some numbers from his phone without user's confirmation. So unless you jailbreak dont expect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make a call using bellow code:-

```
NSString *value =@"9999999999";//your telnumber
NSURL *url = [[ NSURL alloc ] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",value]];

NSLog(@"currunt number%@",url);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Be careful your app could be rejected if you make a call without asking user's confirmation

Comment: yes bits 1.5 and 2 year ago may be that time apple approve that. :)

Comment: This code does not return to the application after the call finishes.

Comment: can u please suggest me which code return back after call finished. then i will improve my answer..@T.J.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help little more

`tel`  directly call the given number without confirmation and did not return to application after call finishes so instead  of it , you may use `telprompt`.

```
     PhoneNumber=@"999999999";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", PhoneNumber]]];
```